# Is there a faster way to read excel files to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have around 700 excel files which needs to be converted to csv files by removing some headers and changing some column names.  I have managed to implement the solution however it is slow. What I found is it takes a lot of time to read excel to a dataframe am using pandas as shown below:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, skiprows=self.skip_rows)
```

I guess there are some unix commands which can do this operation in quick time. However I would like a solution in python. Is there any other library which is faster? Also I would like to know why it takes longer to read excel files, I can understand if we want to preserve the styles, colors from the excel it should take longer. However in my case all I need is to read it into a dataframe.

Following are the version numbers:

- python: 2.7.12
- pandas: 0.21.0
- xlrd: 1.0.0

Comment: What do you intend to do with the data? Most of the bottleneck is in parsing your data. You can usually see some speed gains by adding `dtype=object`, which makes no assumptions about your data and should be much faster.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: well in the question it says the OP wants to convert it to CSV files.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Yes, well, they also want to `removing some headers and changing some column names`, so I don't think just a conversion is what they're looking for.

Comment: @COLDSPEED: Just to clarify i want to skip some rows, change some column names and save it as a csv file. There is further processing I do (multiple times) but they will be done on csv fles as it is much faster that way.

Answer (score 1):

I found that pandas was slow for reading large excel workbooks in python. Openpylx can also be slow, but if you are only interested in getting values from the excel worksheet, there is a way that is significantly faster.

1. Open the workbook as readonly using openpyxl
2. get the desired worksheet
3. Use the worksheet.values iterator, use islice to extract only the range you want. You can pass in column numbers or strings for column ids

These functions will return the range of values you specify very quickly.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from copy import copy,deepcopy
from itertools import islice
import string

def col2num(col):
    num = 0
    for c in col:
        if c in string.ascii_letters:
            num = num * 26 + (ord(c.upper()) - ord('A')) + 1
    return num

def get_worksheet_range(ws, r_start=1,c_start=1,r_end=-1,c_end=-1):
    if isinstance(c_start,int)==False:
        c_start=col2num(c_start)
    if isinstance(c_end,int)==False:
        c_end=col2num(c_end)
    if r_end<=0: r_end=ws.max_row
    if c_end<=0: c_end=ws.max_row
    outrange=[x[:] for x in [[None] * (c_end-c_start+1)] * (r_end-r_start+1)]
    i=0
    for row in islice(ws.values,r_start-1,r_end):
        j=0
        for value in islice(row,c_start-1,c_end-1):
            outrange[i][j]=value;j=j+1
        i=i+1
    return outrange

wb=load_workbook(filename=r"c:\some_excel_file.xlsx",read_only=True) 
ws=wb['SomeWorkSheet']
datarange=get_worksheet_range(ws)
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work for me. I just get a list containing None-values or does this not work on python3?

Comment: do not use this! if you want to sort or manipulate your data later, openpyxl does not support sorting and many stuff !

Comment: Not sure if this code works or not, but I can vouch that load_workbook(..., read_only=True) can lead to huge speedups vs Pandas for xlsx files. See openpyxl docs: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html